# How do I make my tooltip appear below my link even if my link is at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I used the library http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip.

The tooltip works almost perfectly, I have just one issue.
When my link is at the bottom of the page, the tooltip appears above him not below. There seems to have a gap between the tooltip and the bottom of the page, but I want my tooltip below my link whatever the position of my link, even if the tooltip will be cutted by the bottom of my page. The user will scroll down, it is not a big deal.

Here it is my code :

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#listToDisplay', {offsetY: -18})">Link</a>
```

Have you got any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Try the property `position` in options - http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip#ss3

Answer (score 0):

Referring to tracevipin's comment here is the code that should work for you

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#listToDisplay', {offsetY: -18, position:2})">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the tooltip still appears above my link if the bottom of the page is too close...